# The wso2mi container does not correctly reflect the parameters of Synapse.properties

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-micro-integrator

I've been attempting to include the parameter in synapse.properties. However, when the pod is launched, it is not found in the file. I tried adding the parameter to the synapse.properties file in the source code, as well as to the deployment.toml file. Nothing, however, works.

I tried adding the parameter to the synapse.properties file in the source code, as well as to the deployment.toml file. Nothing, however, works.

**In source code, I have added the parameters in synapse.properties:**

```
#configuration for the external debugger channels if server is started in debug mode


synapse.commons.json.output.autoPrimitive=false
synapse.json.output.skipNulls=true
```

**In deployment.toml:**

```
[synapse.commons.json.output]
autoPrimitive=false

[synapse.json.output]
skipNulls=true
```

Container's synapse.properties:

```
opentracing.enable = false
inbound.threads.core = 20
synapse.debugger.port.command = 9005
synapse.debugger.port.event = 9006
internal.https.api.port = 9154
synapse.xpath.func.extensions = org.wso2.micro.integrator.mediation.security.vault.xpath.SecureVaultLookupXPathFunctionProvider,org.wso2.micro.integrator.mediation.security.vault.external.hashicorp.HashiCorpVaultLookupXPathFunctionProvider
jaeger.sender.agent.host = localhost
synapse.commons.json.preserve.namespace = false
jaeger.reporter.log.spans = false
internal.http.api.enabled = true
inbound.port.offset.enable = false
synapse.temp_data.chunk.size = 3072
mediation.flow.statistics.enable = false
mediation.flow.statistics.collect.all = false
internal.http.api.port = 9191
synapse.threads.core = 20
opentracing.zipkin.backend.url = http://localhost:9411/api/v2/spans
jaeger.reporter.flush.interval = 10000
inbound.threads.max = 100
synapse.global_timeout_interval = 120000
jaeger.sampler.manager.host = localhost
opentracing.zipkin.enable = false
synapse.script.mediator.pool.size = 15
jaeger.reporter.max.queue.size = 100
mediation.flow.statistics.tracer.collect.properties = false
synapse.threads.max = 100
jaeger.sender.agent.port = 6831
statistics.clean.enable = true
mediation.flow.statistics.tracer.collect.payloads = false
statistics.clean.interval = 1000
jaeger.sampler.manager.port = 5778
synapse.sal.endpoints.sesssion.timeout.default=600000
synapse.carbon.ext.tenant.info=org.wso2.micro.integrator.initializer.handler.MITenantInfoConfigurator
mediation.flow.statistics.event.consume.interval=1000
mediation.flow.statistics.event.clean.interval=15000
```